# How to increase the size of the activity indicator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, loader

I am newbie on IOS Development. I Created a `UIWebView`.

When the application launches I implemented the loader.

Now I want the loader to be a little bigger in size with some background image.

My code is this:

```
    private var loadingObservation: NSKeyValueObservation?

    private lazy var loadingIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = {
        let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView()
        spinner.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        spinner.color = .black

        return spinner
    }()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        loadingObservation = webView.observe(\.isLoading, options: [.new, .old]) { [weak self] (_, change) in
            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

            // this is fine
            let new = change.newValue!
            let old = change.oldValue!

            if new && !old {
                strongSelf.view.addSubview(strongSelf.loadingIndicator)
                strongSelf.loadingIndicator.startAnimating()
                NSLayoutConstraint.activate([strongSelf.loadingIndicator.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: strongSelf.view.centerXAnchor),
                                             strongSelf.loadingIndicator.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: strongSelf.view.centerYAnchor)])
                strongSelf.view.bringSubviewToFront(strongSelf.loadingIndicator)
            }
            else if !new && old {
                strongSelf.loadingIndicator.stopAnimating()
                strongSelf.loadingIndicator.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }


        let myURL = URL(string: "http://192.168.1.4:8080")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)


    }
```

By this code I am getting the result like this:

[image]

Is there any expert on IOS who can help me out regarding this.

I want to increase the size of Loader. Any help is really appreciated regarding this. Thanks

Comment: spinner.style = .whiteLarge     -   try this

Comment: try `spinner.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .whiteLarge`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try setting `loadingIndicator.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 2, y: 2)`

Comment: From where I have to put this code?

Comment: You put into viewDidLoad method or lazy block of loadingIndicator property (use name spinner)

Comment: @Aks Does it work?

Comment: Yes it works. I Also want some background image just behind the loader

Answer (score 2):

Make `extension` of `UIActivityIndicatorView` -

```
extension UIActivityIndicatorView {
    func scaleIndicator(factor: CGFloat) {
        transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: factor, y: factor)
    }
}
```

Then can access `scaleIndicator()` method from your `UIActivityIndicatorView` object anywhere -

```
activityIndicatorView.scaleIndicator(factor: 2.5)
```